# Excel not writing to specific sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have tried googling but it doesnt seem to help

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook output_workbook = excelApp.workbooks.Add(misvalue);
Excel.Worksheet output = output_workbook.Sheets.getItem(2);
output.Activate();

//do something here
output.Cells[1,1] = ""
```

It seems i have hard coded it to be the second sheet but it seems it stills give me the first sheet.

I have tried other methods like

output = output.WorkSheets[2]; it still doesnt work

Comment: does the 2nd sheet exist, do you need to create it first?

Comment: maybe you need parentheses `output = output.WorkSheets(2);`

Comment: have you tried with `output.Sheets("SheetName")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Excel.Worksheet output = output_workbook.Worksheets.getItem(2);
```

I use Worksheets.getItem(value); and it works fine.